# I can`t resolve problem with cursor focus in draft.js

Tags: syntax-highlighting, draftjs, highlight.js

I use highlight.js to enable syntax highliting in draft.js editor,but when type three quotes to toggle code-block my cursor moves in two steps left and I can type only in the first string.When I try to press enter to move to the next string,my cursor just moves in the beginning of the first string.Here is my code:

```
import React, {FC, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import styles from './editor.module.scss';
import PluginEditor from '@draft-js-plugins/editor';
import Editor from '@draft-js-plugins/editor';
import {
    AtomicBlockUtils,
    EditorState,
    RichUtils,
    DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap, genKey,
} from 'draft-js';

import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core';
import javascript from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript';
const ArticleEditor: FC = () => {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
        () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
    );
    
    
    const onEditorStateChange = (editorState: EditorState) => {
        setEditorState(editorState);
    };
    
    
    const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const selection = editorState.getSelection();
    const block = currentContent.getBlockForKey(selection.getStartKey());
    const currentInlineStyle = editorState.getCurrentInlineStyle();
    const blockText = block.getText();
    const symbolCount = blockText.split('#').length;
    let starCount = blockText.split('*').length;
    let hyphenCount = blockText.split('_').length;
    let tildeCount = blockText.split('~').length;
    const quoteCount = blockText.split('`').length;
    
    hljs.registerLanguage('javascript', javascript);
    
    const keyBindingFn = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<NonNullable<unknown>>) => {
        
        switch (event.key) {
            
            case '`':
                if (quoteCount % 3 == 0) {
                    onEditorStateChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(editorState, 'code-block'));
                } else if (quoteCount % 6 == 0) {
                    onEditorStateChange(RichUtils.toggleBlockType(editorState, 'unstyled'));
                    
                }
                break;
          
    };
    
    
    const CodeBlock = (props: { block: any; contentState: any; }) => {
        const { block, contentState } = props;
        const key = genKey();
        const language = contentState.getBlockForKey(block.key).getData().get('language') || 'javascript';
        
        const code = contentState.getBlockForKey(block.key).getText();
        
        const highlightedCode = hljs.highlight(language, code).value;
        
        return <pre key={key}><code dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: highlightedCode }} /></pre>;
    };
    
    const blockRenderer = (block: { getType: () => string; }) => {
        if (block.getType() === 'code-block') {
            return {
                component: CodeBlock,
                editable: true,
            };
        }
        return null;
    };
    
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.article__editor} onClick={event => handleClick(event)}
                 onFocus={focus}>
                
                <Editor
                    blockRenderMap={extendedBlockRenderMap}
                    editorState={editorState}
                    onChange={onEditorStateChange}
                    keyBindingFn={(event) => keyBindingFn(event)}
                    plugins={plugins}
                    ref={editorRef}
                    blockRendererFn={blockRenderer}
                />
            
            </div>
    );
};
```

I will be very appriciated for any help.

I tried to set html string directly to the editorState but it doesn`t work